# Filtering MySQL entries by date in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Currently I'm using CodeIgniters MVC framework to fetch my records between a particular time period. I have done the same filtering for a dropdown and achieved the result, but I cant figure out how to do the same with a date picker. The following is my View model:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
        <div id="statusModal">
    <input type="date" name="startDate" class="startDate" id="startDate"/>
    <input type="date" name="endDate" class="endDate" id="endDate"/>
    <select name="status" class="status" id="status">
        <option>Draft</option>
        <option>Unpublish</option>
        <option>Publish</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="alertbox" id="alertbox" name="alertbox">alertbox</button>
    <br/><br/>    
    <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        load_status();
        
    $('#alertbox').click(function(){
        var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
        if(startDate != '' && endDate != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>testcontroller/fetch_dat",
            method:"POST",
            data:{startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate},
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').html(data)
            }
        })
        }else{
            alert("Please enter a date");
        }
    })

        function load_status(status){
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>testcontroller/fetch_stat",
                method:"POST",
                data:{status:status},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data)
                }
            })
        }

        $('#status').click(function(){
            var search = $(this).val();
            if(search != ''){
                load_status(search);
            }
            else{
                load_status();
            }
        })
    })

</script>
```

Controller Class:

```
class Testcontroller extends CI_Controller
   {  
      public function index() 
      { 
      $this->load->view('crm/test');      
       }
         function fetch_dat(){
            $output ='';
            $startDate = '';
            $endDate = '';
            $this->load->model('crm/user_model');
  
            if($this->input->post('startDate')){
              $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
            }
            if($this->input->post('endDate')){
               $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
             }
            $data = $this->user_model->fetch_date($startDate,$endDate);
            
            $output .= '
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Customer id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Added Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
  
                    </tr>
              ';
           if($data->num_rows() > 0)
           {
              foreach($data->result() as $row)
              {
              $output .= '
                 <tr>
                 <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->added_date.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->status.'</td>
                 </tr>
              ';
              }
           }
           else
           {
              $output .= '<tr>
                 <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                 </tr>';
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
           }

         function fetch_stat(){
            $output ='';
            $status = '';
            $this->load->model('crm/user_model');
  
            if($this->input->post('status')){
              $status = $this->input->post('status');
            }
            $data = $this->user_model->fetch_status($status);
            
            $output .= '
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Customer id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Added Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
  
                    </tr>
              ';
           if($data->num_rows() > 0)
           {
              foreach($data->result() as $row)
              {
              $output .= '
                 <tr>
                 <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->added_date.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->status.'</td>
                 </tr>
              ';
              }
           }
           else
           {
              $output .= '<tr>
                 <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                 </tr>';
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
           }
      }
```

And my model class:

```
function fetch_status($status){
        $this->db->select(*);
        $this->db->from(crm_listings);
        if($status != ''){
            $this->db->where('status',$status);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function fetch_date($startDate,$endDate){
        $this->db->select(*);
        $this->db->from(crm_listings);
        if($startDate != '' && $endDate != ''){
            $this->db->where('added_date BETWEEN "' . $startDate . '" AND "' . $endDate . '"',$startDate,$endDate);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

Comment: what is data type of added_date in database table?

Comment: @umefarooq it is datetime

Comment: can you tell me $startDate and $endDate format is it same datetime or just date?

Comment: @umefarooq how can I check that? both these variables are the ones that I'm picking from my input tag and they both have to refer the added_date column in my database

Comment: in your controller fetch simply echo $startDate and endDate and die(); you will able to see date format

Comment: Yes thier format is 2021-10-05 which is datetime

Comment: @umefarooq so I've edited the function in view model for the date function and now I get a no data found when I click the button. Is this because in my database the format is 2021-09-28 11:04:52 but when I echo the $startDate I get 2021-10-05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi after all comments on above post as you are getting $startDate and $endDate in Y-m-d format here is my answer you need to cast added_date to just date in where query here is how you can do it.

```
 function fetch_date($startDate,$endDate){
        $this->db->select(*);
        $this->db->from(crm_listings);
        if($startDate != '' && $endDate != ''){
            $this->db->where('cast(added_date as date) BETWEEN "' . $startDate . '" AND "' . $endDate . '"',null,false);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

it will work for you.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you, but I added a count(*) in my statement to get the number of rows for the data but I cant get the number to display. I think it has something to do with my controller class, but I dont know what to change

Comment: can you share your select?

Comment: It's your same code just changed $this->db->select("count(*)");

Comment: @umefarooq sir please describe about `cast()`

Comment: @Jay Vijay Modi what is your next task?

Comment: @KUMAR its just type casting like all programing language your just changing value of specific column one type to another like datetime to just date, read more here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/

Comment: $this->db->select("*,count(id) as total"); try it.

Comment: @KUMAR Hi, can you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450553/retrieving-number-of-rows-with-a-particular-value-after-filtering-query-through

Comment: Hey @umefarooq could you also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517157/table-count-data-not-showing-up-in-view-class